# jquery new id for img active

Tags: jquery

I'm using this code:
http://jsfiddle.net/fGHmF/2/

now I want to add the word "size" to every IMG id. for instance:

```
    <img src='images/size1.png' alt='img1' id='size1' />
    <img src='images/size2.png' alt='img2' id='size2' />
    <img src='images/size3.png' alt='img3' id='size3' />
    <img src='images/size4.png' alt='img4' id='size4' />
```

what do i need to change in the java script?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: check this: http://jsfiddle.net/fGHmF/4/

Comment: Why would you need to change the ids of your img elements? If you have code that accesses, e.g., the first one as `size1` can't it access it as `1`?

Comment: I added your jsfiddle code to your question so that it will be useful to future visitors even if the fiddle should disappear.

Comment: @Roi do not forget to accept an answer when it solved your problem. Users that follow SO rules tend to get more help from other users. If you do not accept answers people will tend not to help you.

Answer (score 6):

```
$('img').attr('id', function() {
   return 'size' + this.id;
});
```

Comment: +1. I was about to post this. Though it should be `'size' + this.id`.

Answer (score 2):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fGHmF/5/)

```
$('img').attr('id', function() {
   return 'size'+this.id;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('img').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('id', 'size' + $(this).attr('id'))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
$('img').each(function(i){
   $(this).attr('id', 'size' + $(this).attr('id')); 
});
```

see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fGHmF/6/)

Comment: Did you test this? Even ignoring the syntax error (missing `.` after `$(this)`) it doesn't do what you think it does, it sets all the img elements to have the same id as each other...